# Delete both Opening and Ending braces simultanously in Eclipse with one Shortkey

Tags: eclipse, shortcut, braces

Is there a way in Eclipse to delete both the opening and the ending braces simultanously  when they are highlighted? Would be nice to have that.

> ```
>     for key in int_vars:
>         int_values.append((getattr(self, key+'_value')))
> ```